# How to use Routing in Angular 6.1

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have been Working on Angular 6. I am stuck in Routing and Navigation part. I am not able to figure out how to do Routing in Angular 6. Can you help me out to Understanding it.

Comment: A very good resource: https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 0):

In your app.module.ts:

import:

```
import {Routes, RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
```

declare a cont with the route path with the component:

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
 { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent }
];
```

and add in import section RouterModule with the constant that holds your routing:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
      .
      .
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})
    ]
    .
    .
    .
})
class AppModule { }
```

in you app.component.html add the following:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Edit:**
use routerLink to navigate from component to another:

```
<a [routerLink]="[/search]"></a>
```

here's a good tutorial: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/route-configuration/

Also see: https://medium.com/all-is-web/https-medium-com-all-is-web-angular-5-routing-fad9b3648f67